# Firefox error - Permission denied to access property "assign"

Tags: firebase-authentication

I'm getting this error in Firefox when following the instruction at [Firebase documents for installing Authentication](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Web#installation) and only with Firefox. I figure it has something to do with the same-origin policy, from all the reading I've done.

Is there a work around needed or is this something that Firebase needs to fix? Or is there some other solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

We saw this issue as well. The "document.domain" fix detailed at

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

solved it for us. Specifically, we added this line in the head section of our html file(s):

```
<script>document.domain = "[your domain name goes here]"</script>
```

Where [your domain name goes here] is a consistent e.g. mysite.com value across the relevant html file(s).